# Modelling non stationary data (loan portfolio default rates)

Tags: modeling

I would be very grateful, if you can advise me on the following:

I am currently building a macroeconomic model, where I try to find dependence of a loan portfolio Default Rates from macro factors

I include to the model stationary (transformed) independent variables (macrofactors), but my DRs are highly non stationary, even when I take first difference (second difference is not meaningful, as it is a very small value).

I also have tried to remove trend, seasonality etc. - does not work (I don't know why, but the ADF test results get even worth).

What shall I do now? Am I right, that the dependent variable (DR) should be stationary also?

Comment: Can you provide atleast graph of your dependent variable?

Answer (score 0):

the ACF for the 1st difference looks rather stationary, but the ADF test shows p value about 0.58 (when lag order manually changed to 6), otherwise, it is around 0.96. Why this happens and how can I overcome it???

By the way, how can I estimate alternative proper number of lags in R (incorporated ADF test suggests me 2 lags).

KPSS pvalue - 0.007 and Ljung-Box = 0.01

I have 20 observations in total (19 after differencing).

The original time series have a clear upper trend and at the end begin to decline